# Creating an Android, IOS, and Windows 10 app browser

Tags: android, ios, html, google-chrome, browser

I have created some web app (websites) using HTML5 tech. I want to create my own web browser specifically designed for my own app/sites. I want the appearance of being native but just have my web app with my custom browser wrapped around it.

I have looked into WebView and think that's what I'm looking. Though the reason I'm asking here is to see if there are other packages like WebView that some of you may think is better? Or to get a confirmation that WebView should give me what I am looking for.

My Background is Programming so development should not be an issue, so I am looking for something that will allow me to fully customize my own web browser to run my web app efficiently. Basically something that's NOT cookie cutter and won't limit me, but at the same time NOT back-end heavy.

I'm looking at WebView right now because it should allow me to quickly make it a native android app. But also looking to do the same on IOS and Windows. Though, I have experience designing a browser using Visual Studio .NET.

Any ideas on where I should start, Thanks!

Comment: whats your question by the way? alternatives for webView or .. what :|

Comment: Heard about PhoneGap or Cordova?

Comment: alternatives if necessary... I've looked int WebView, though not programmed anything with it yet, but it does look promising. My question is how detailed and efficient is WebView at allowing me to program something (virtually from scratch) without limiting me of some key features. And then what are alternatves, thanks for responding

Comment: from what I have found with PhoneGap and Cordova is that they just wrap the HTML5 code to the mobile device, correct me if I'm wrong. But the reason I really like to do my own web browser is so users can follow links from my app/site to www pages. Looking to create something link the Dolphin Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a web browser so users can follow links from your app...or site....to other sites on the web?

Why not just create a "link" in your app  then create a webview to display the content. I think you are biting more than you can chew....or should chew.

Comment: I know how to do it and think I can do it. I've been looking into Webview. My main question is more in line of best practices. But from all I find webview seems to be the way to go. The reason I asked the question is because I notice that in the Javascript and framework package world, some packages seems to depreciate very fast as well as new packages seem to make others obsolete. So I just wanted to make sure that webview was the best way to go with this! Thanks

Comment: and while I'm a pretty season programmer (over 25 years), I have yet to create an app in Android or any mobile device

Comment: I think you might be over thinking it. If your main concerns are having web content in an android app, you miht want to look into PhoneGap. If you want APIs, or specific layouts (tablayout, expandablelist), etc, figure it out in android studio